# From Titanium to Native Android

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, native, appcelerator

I have an application that was originally built in titanium and I have now re-built the app in native android code. The problem is that when I try to install my new native app over the top of the titanium app I get this error:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

it then asks me if I want to uninstall the old application - I say "yes" and then I get this error:

DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Obviously if I change the applicationID I can avoid this issue, but since the titanium app is already in the play store, I want to be able to upload my new APK as an update, rather then building a whole new app for my users to download.

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I solved my own problem.. Turns out the problem was to do with android:authorities being different. I had to refactor my package name to be the same as my applicationId and that seemed to fix the problem for me.